# Java and LibGDX - Unable to find gwt.xml

Tags: java, android, gwt, libgdx

I'm trying to deploy my project but I am facing some problems. When I try to build the APK on Android Studio I get this error:

[image]

Honestly I never had contact with .gwt files before and I don´t know what they are. I searched on google about gwt but I did not understand very well what I read.

Here is my project hierarchy:

[image]

I remember that I had this file before but I think I deleted it by mistake. I also think this file was generated by LibGDX setup.

Anyway, my question is, how can I solve this problem or how can I make my own gwt.xml file for this project and why is it needed?

Thanks.

Comment: reopen a new libgdx program and paste the code in the right directory?

Comment: Are you trying to build for HTML? Because that is not the Android build task

Comment: @Marius, no I am trying to build for android. Is it possible that I am doing it wrong? I went to 'Build' -> 'Build APK'

Comment: @Tacolibre I tried to create a new project. For some reason the gwt.xml file was not created and I could not see his content.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the core main file and not the html file? I am just guessing at this point dude